# How can a website prevent a user from accessing it using different PCs?

Tags: web, authentication

I was signing up for a paid website, and the terms of service included a clause that says I may access the website using only the PC I used when I signed up for it (I assume this is to prevent me from spreading my user/password around for friends, etc.).

I was wondering, is enforcing this clause technologically possible, without installing third party software on a user PC? If so, by what methods? How can a user potentially fool such system (for example, if his "sign up PC" dies)?

Comment: You can have many restrictions. IP address, MAC address, hardware combinations, certificates, etc.

Comment: This will not work since user can change the browser, reinstall OS, etc. Actully, there is no real/good way for website to check this. Only IP check, but this is not helpful.

Comment: It's means that if your IP changes ,you are basically violating TOS ? ... there is no way they can track which PC you are using directly, they can get your browser , your IP , stuffs like that but they just cant know what pc you are using exactly. I saw only this kind of TOS on porn sites , to prevent login/password sharing, if too mainly people with different IPs log with the same login at the same time, the login will be blocked.

Comment: @SmartK8 can a website know your PC MAC address? Even if so, wouldn't using a router only show the router's address? Also, wouldn't changing connection type, for example, wired instead of wireless, change my PCs MAC address as well? I know some software can lock its license to you specific hardware combo, but can a website really have access to so much info w/o installing third party software?

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm not advocating for such approach. I'm just saying it is POSSIBLE, if really desired. No one will care if you changed your IP, that's your problem, and you have no access now (which you desire, not the provider) unless you contact the website provider to change your access options. MAC address is retrievable via ActiveX (as well as hardware informations), that would be a technology to use. If the user don't like the conditions, well tough. But this is all just hypothetical. In real life, the websites don't work like this. But you asked, I'm just giving you the answer.